# How to get MD5 certification fingerprint

Tags: android

I have created my own `Keystore` and to get the `MD5 Certification Fingerprint Key` , I am writing the following command :

```
C:\Users\XX\.android>keytool -list -alias mykey -keystore mykey.keystore
```

and it returns

```
mykey, 16 Jul, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 40:6A:97:77:FE:25:55:25:03:D2:8E:93:FD:74:21:A7:52:XX:YY:ZZ
```

whereas I was looking for MD5 key because whenever I am trying to obtain `GoogleMap Api` Key using this it says :

```
    The fingerprint that you entered is not valid.
```

Please help me to get the `MD5 key`.
Also if possible briefly describe what is the difference between these two types keys

Thanks.

Comment: To get MD5 key Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) . In this link you have to paste your Certificate fingerprint that you mentioned in your question for get MD5 key for google map. Check this [link](http://www.icodeya.com/2011/04/how-to-get-your-md5-fingerprint-for.html) for get your certification key using eclipse key. It is very easy .

Comment: Yes I tried with this only, but whenver I was trying to generate key It was saying :" The fingerprint that you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint. "

Answer (score 4):

just add -v after keytool

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Open the command prompt and follow the steps

D:\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\tools>keytool -genkey -v -keystore projectkey.keystore -alias aliasname -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 15000
Enter keystore password: ------------
What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]: ------------
What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]: ------------
What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]: ------------
What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]: ------------
What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]: ------------
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]: ------------

D:\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\tools>keytool -v -list -alias aliasname -keystore projectkey.keystore
Enter keystore password:
aliasname, Dec 7, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): CA:CF:AA:0E:5A:2B:88:C8:64:F1:FA:F7:29:21:50:FF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I thinks the query is not correct ,

C:\Users\XX.android>keytool -list -alias mykey -keystore mykey.keystore

because for a md5 key you first go to jdk bin 

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin> 

then run the following command  
keytool -list -alias the_alias_name_of_keystore -keystore
keystore_with_full_path  like

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>keytool -list -alias map -keystore
D:\SampleMap

and  it gives you output like

Enter keystore password:
SampleMap, Apr 6, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 4F:63:53:33:33:5A:79:F6:53:C2:33:E6:E7:A6:8F:C9
```