# How obtain the google map API key for publish the app in google play?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use debug certificate for developing app, but just I have finished the app, I want to publish the app in google play. Do i need the other API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515519/i-just-finished-my-first-android-app-today-now-i-want-to-publish-it/11515699#11515699 see this shall be helpful and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504527/how-to-get-md5-certification-fingerprint/11505494#11505494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish on Google Play, you will need to sign the apk with your own unique key, as detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Once you have created your own unique key, you will need to get its MD5 hash and obtain a maps API key for it, like you did for the debug certificate.